# Removing write-protected'ness of a file system from terminal in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, flash

I recently saw that my 2GB SanDisk microSD card was mounting as read-only filesystem on my linux (Ubuntu 10.10). I tried changing its property through nautilus, but it went in vain.

Also I tried manually editing /etc/mtab file where I edited "ro" option to "rw", but when the flash-drive was again inserted, it was mounted as read-only.

Can anyone tell me how I can remove this write-protect property of this filesystem to read-write in linux?

Answer (score 1):

Full sized SD cards have a write protect switch.

I do not have a microSD card here to see if they also have one. But it is worth checking. If you are using a microSD to SD convertor then also check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /wherever/card/is/mounted
```

Comment: I already tried that and got the following mount error: **mount: cannot remount block device /dev/sdb read-write, is write-protected** . Also I tried formatting the filesystem to FAT32 using **mkfs** and with **gparted** but in vain

Comment: are there any messages in `dmesg` when plugging it in?

Comment: @krissi yes, as I have said I got write-protect is on when I did a dmesg as **[19686.432282] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is on**

Comment: Can be a hardware switch, see answer of @Hennes